# Need help retrieving dictionary from text file

Tags: python

I am trying to retrieve the dictionaries I created into a text file to list them in the console but running into a 'list index out of range' which is being caused by one of the values being a list.

This is how it shows up in the textfile:

```
{'Email': 'jbond@gmail.com', 'First Name': 'James', 'Last Name': 'Bond', 'Department': 'HR', 'Position': 'Manager', 'Salary': 50000.0, 'Skills': ['Organizer', 'speech']}
{'Email': 'jdoe@gmail.com', 'First Name': 'Jane', 'Last Name': 'Doe', 'Department': 'IT', 'Position': 'Help Desk', 'Salary': 35000.0, 'Skills': ['Troubleshooting']}
{'Email': 'johnd@gmail.com', 'First Name': 'John', 'Last Name': 'Doe', 'Department': 'IT', 'Position': 'Manager', 'Salary': 80000.0, 'Skills': ['Troubleshooting', 'Managing']}
```

Trying to retrieve the information to display all of it as well as be able to retrieve information just for one person (haven't started yet on this since haven't figured how to retrieve and display for all)

I created a parse function and another function that calls on that to display the information. Here is the code for those two functions.

```
def viewEmployees():
    f = open("sample.txt", 'rt')
    lines = f.read().split('\n')
    for l in lines:
        if l != '':
            employee_list = parse(l)
            print(employee_list)
    f.close()

def parse(d):
    dictionary = dict()

    pairs = d.strip('{}').split(', ')
    for i in pairs:
        pair = i.split(': ')

        dictionary[pair[0].strip('\'\'"\"')] = pair[1].strip('\'\'"\"')
    return dictionary

viewEmployees()
```

The output I am wanting is to at least show up like it does in the text file. If I can find a way to have it look like this instead that would be cool.

```
Email: jbond@gmail.com
First Name: James
Last Name: Bond
Department: HR
Position: Manager
Salary: 50000.00
Skills: Organizer, Speech

Email: jdoe@gmail.com
First Name: Jane
Last Name: Doe
Department: IT
Position: Help Desk
Salary: 35000.00
Skills: Troubleshooting
```

Here is the error message I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\OneDrive\Desktop\sample.py", line 20, in <module>       
    viewEmployees()
  File "d:\OneDrive\Desktop\sample.py", line 6, in viewEmployees   
    employee_list = parse(l)
  File "d:\OneDrive\Desktop\sample.py", line 17, in parse
    dictionary[pair[0].strip('\'\'"\"')] = pair[1].strip('\'\'"\"')
IndexError: list index out of range
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction in figuring this out it would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: post your code here as text please

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to provide a [mre] including complete code (e.g. the call to `viewEmployees()`), expected output, and the full error message with traceback. As well, it'd help to phrase the problem as a question. For more tips, see [ask].

Comment: Also, you need to provide the input as text, [not a picture](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). You can [edit] it in and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Comment: Your code also needs to be properly formatted, but there's a suggested edit to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're reading a text file that contains one serialized JSON object by line of the file.

So, an efficient way would be to read line by line the file, as you did, and for each line read, call some JSON parser library to do the work for you.
Check how to do it : https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_json.asp

In short, you replace your `parse(l)` by `json.loads(l)` (after importing it) call that will do exactly what your parse function aims to do, but will handle every case possible, and so arrays.
This `json.loads` function will return you a dictionary object with all the informations of one person.

---

Do this, except if it is an exercise to train you on creating parsers and parsing rules, of course.